# How to hide a border?

Tags: html, css

I have a div class `.text-center` and I'm trying to hide the border for a button.

The css is:

```
.text-center:nth-of-type(even){border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px; border: none;}
```

This gives it a 10px border radius, but won't allow 20px border-radius or allow me to hide the border which is obscuring the button.

Also tried:

```
.text-center a {border: none !important; box-shadow : none;}
```

But this hides the border for other buttons. How is that possible when the `a` is only listed under that div class?

Could this be a specificity issue? Tried framing `.text-center` within the div class above it-nothing

Html:

```
    <div class="event_registration registration">

    <input type="button" class="registration_button button" value="Register for event" />

    <div class="registration_details">
        <p>To register for this event please visit the following URL: <a href="https://dice.fm/festival/camden-rocks-festival?_branch_match_id=655373442484550779" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://dice.fm/festival/camden-rocks-festival?_branch_match_id=655373442484550779 &rarr;</a></p>     </div>
        </div>
                 <!-- For more details information start -->
                          <div class="text-center">
                <a class="link-button" data-toggle="modal" href="https://www.theunderworldcamden.co.uk/event/camden-rocks-festival-2019/"  target="_blank" >View More Details</a>
              </div> 

         <!-- For more details infomation end-->
         <!-- Video popup box section start -->
                     <!-- Video popup box section end -->
        &nbsp;


 <!-- Event Location and Time start-->   

    <h3 class="section-title">When & Where</h3>
      <ul class="when-where">
        <li class="event-start-date">                                          
         From:2019-06-01 &nbsp; 12:00 PM            </li>
        <li class="event-end-date">                                             
         To:2019-06-02&nbsp;12:00 AM            </li>
        <li class="event-location">                     
         Location:
                       <span class="venue-name"> 
            The Underworld
```

https://adsler.co.uk/event/camden-rocks-festival/

Comment: share a complete and valid HTML code

Comment: .entry-content a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

Comment: @JustCode Will that target only that button?

Comment: Yes it will. your button has border and box shadow property

Comment: Hey @JustCode that worked. Thanks. Put it in an answer and I'll mark correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try, in `.link-button` class, to remove `border` and `box-shadow` attributes

Comment: Will that target just that button?

Comment: no, all the ones using that class. If this button is different, you should create a diffirent class without those attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.entry-content a { 
display: inline-block; 
border: none; 
text-decoration: none; 
box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your A link has a shadow and border on it

```
a.link-button {
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 4px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
padding: 8px 7px;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

Place this in your CSS and it should remove it from that link button. I would suggest giving the link and ID and remove it only from that link as to not affect any others.

Answer (score 0):

If this button is unique then you should target it with an `#id`.

However if this was me I would make a `borderless` class and apply it only to the buttons I want to omit borders from.

As long as this class is listed after your other button styles it will overide any noted stylings.

```css
.borderless {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="link-button borderless" data-toggle="modal" href="https://www.theunderworldcamden.co.uk/event/camden-rocks-festival-2019/" target="_blank">View More Details</a>
```

**NOTE**

Ensure the specificity of this style is greater than your other classes to ensure it is applied and to avoid using `!important`

If this will only be applied to anchor tags for example use:

```
a.borderless{}
```

Comment: Thanks. So where would I insert `<a class="link-button borderless" data-toggle="modal" href="https://www.theunderworldcamden.co.uk/event/camden-rocks-festival-2019/" target="_blank">View More Details</a>`? I'm using WordPress so...